# How should MVC pattern look like in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to discuss some details about implementing the MVC pattern in laravel. Actually I think about one issue. The role of a controller.

I have noticed that many developers write a controller code as follows : they get some data from a request, pass this data to a model, get processed data from a model and send it back to a view. In short -  controller queries the model and passes the result to the view.

I found an interesting article about MVC pattern.
https://r.je/views-are-not-templates

According to the article above, such controler implementation is wrong. The author gives many convincing arguments. What do you think about it? Should we access models directly in a view?

Comment: Only, in  your description, it is not a "model" but a table-abstraction, not a "view" but a template and .. well .. I think you might be already figuring out that it is not actually a "controller" :D  Also, I wrote few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) regarding that some years ago, might be useful.

Comment: Nice answer shared by you, gonna read by myself.

Comment: Let me get this straight. The controller class in laravel is not a controller in mvc?

Comment: At best is a merger of view and controller responsibilities. Usually with service layer being merged into it too.